# Запись данных в mysql (массив)

Tags: php, mysql

Код :

```
 $id = [123,321,456];

foreach ($id as $value) {
if ($connection->query("UPDATE collparams SET MPN='$value'") === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
}
}
```

Запись в базу происходит, но всем ячейкам дается последнее значение массива **456**, А нужно по порядку : 123 в первую ячейку, 321 во вторую и так далее.

Как исправить данную проблему ?

p.s:Еще стоит учитывать что в массив будет не из 3 значений а стремиться к "бесконечности".

Comment: update без условия where модифицирует все записи в базе, надо задать условие однозначно идентифицирующее запись, которую надо обновить. Уловие точно такое же, как если бы вы эту одну запись хотели бы получить select'ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно подготовить ассоциативный массив для записи состоящий из id записи и нужного значения:

```
$id = ['1'=>123,'2'=>321,'10'=>456];
```

затем циклом записать:

```
foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
if ($connection->query("UPDATE collparams SET MPN='$value' WHERE id='$key'") === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
}
}
```